# How I can rotate the x-axis FrameTicks?

Tags: plotting

I don´t have idea how to make them rotate. Can anybody help me?

[image: Plot]

Comment: Why not post the data and the code in a format people can easily copy? People are less likely to help you if you do not make it easy for them to try things out.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site). Once read the edit window help button `?` gives quick reminders of that material. To remove from the screen, click `?` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some data to emulate `datos8` and `datos9`.

```
datos8 = {{1, 0}, {2, 10}, {3, 40}, {4, 110}, {5, 15}, {6, 4.5}, {7, 
   73.6}, {8, 20.5}, {9, 212}, {10, 57.5}, {11, 46.8}, {12, 32}, {13, 
   8}, {14, 181.5}, {15, 118}, {16, 35}, {17, 106}, {18, 81}, {19, 
   48.5}, {20, 14}};

datos9 = {{1, 4.5}, {2, 10}, {3, 30}, {4, 78}, {5, 10}, {6, 10}, {7, 
   26}, {8, 26}, {9, 75}, {10, 75}, {11, 20}, {12, 20}, {13, 20}, {14,
    67}, {15, 67}, {16, 67}, {17, 67}, {18, 54}, {19, 54}, {20, 54}};
```

Below is your plot in the current state:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {datos8, datos9},
 PlotRange -> {{1, 20}, {0, 250}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Determinante", "Traza"}, Right],
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Blue, Thickness[0.002]},
   {Green, Thickness[0.002]}
   },
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Orbital atómico", "Dispersión"},
 FrameTicks -> {
   {
    {50, 100, 150, 200, 250},
    None
    },
   {
    {
     {1, "1s"}, {2, "2s"}, {3, "3s"}, {4, "4s"},
     {5, "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(s\)]\)"}, {6, 
      "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"}, {7, "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(s\)]\)"}, {8, 
      "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"},
     {9, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(z\)]\)"}, {10, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"}, {11, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]]\)"}, \
{12, "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(xz\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(yz\)]\)"},
     {13, 
      "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(xy\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] \
- \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"}, {14, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]]\)"}, \
{15, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(xz\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(yz\)]\)"}, {16, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(xy\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] \
- \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"},
     {17, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(3\)]]\)"}, \
{18, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(xz\), \(2\)]]\),4\!\
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(yz\), \(2\)]]\)"}, {19, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \
\(xyz\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(z \((\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)])\)\)]\)"}, {20, 
      "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(x \((\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)] - 3 \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \
\(3\)])\)\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(y \((3 \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)])\)\)]\
\)"}
     },
    None
    }
   },
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There may very well be an easier way but one method that works it to extract the x-axes frame ticks from the plot and use `Map` to wrap `Rotate` the strings.

```
ticks = Map[{#[[1]], Rotate[#[[2]], π/2]} &, {
    {1, "1s"}, {2, "2s"}, {3, "3s"}, {4, "4s"},
    {5, "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(s\)]\)"}, {6, 
     "2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"}, {7, "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(s\)]\)"}, {8, 
     "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"},
    {9, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(z\)]\)"}, {10, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(x\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(y\)]\)"}, {11, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]]\)"}, \
{12, "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(xz\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \
\(yz\)]\)"},
    {13, "3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(xy\)]\),3\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] \
- \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"}, {14, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]]\)"}, \
{15, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(xz\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(yz\)]\)"}, {16, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \(xy\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(d\), \
\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \
\(2\)]\)]\)"},
    {17, "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \
\(3\)]]\)"}, {18, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(xz\), \(2\)]]\),4\!\
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), SuperscriptBox[\(yz\), \(2\)]]\)"}, {19, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \
\(xyz\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(z \((\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)])\)\)]\)"}, {20, 
     "4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(x \((\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)] - 3 \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \
\(3\)])\)\)]\),4\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(y \((3 \
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)] - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)])\)\)]\
\)"}
    }];
```

Now remake your plot using the `ticks` with the rotated strings

```
ListLinePlot[
 {datos8, datos9},
 PlotRange -> {{1, 20}, {0, 250}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Determinante", "Traza"}, Right],
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Blue, Thickness[0.002]},
   {Green, Thickness[0.002]}
   },
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Orbital atómico", "Dispersión"},
 FrameTicks -> {
   {
    {50, 100, 150, 200, 250},
    None
    },
   {
    ticks,
    None
    }
   },
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! It works.